# Closing ZipOutputStream

Tags: java, zip

I'm a bit confused. I know that an empty zip is not legal. But what about this sample snippet:

```
ZipOutputStream zos = null; 
try
{
    zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("..."));
    //
    //..
    //
}
finally
{
    zos.close();
}
```

If no zip entries had been added for some reason (possibly exceptional situation) then the following exception will be thrown on close attempt:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP file must have at least one entry
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.finish(ZipOutputStream.java:304)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:146)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.close(ZipOutputStream.java:321)
```

In this situation what would be the cleanest way to close the stream?

Thanks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should close the `FileOutputStream`, not the `ZipOutputStream`, because the former is what actually consumes system resources.

```
File zipFile = new File("/tmp/example.zip");
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try
{
   fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
   ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

   // ...

   zos.close();
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
   // log/report exception, then delete the invalid file
   IOUtils.closeQuietly(fos);
   zipFile.delete();
}
finally
{
   IOUtils.closeQuietly(fos);
}
```

The `IOUtils` class is found in [Jakarta Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/). Using it means that you don't have to deal with the possible-but-rarely-useful `IOException` that can be thrown by `close()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this should be the truth :-)

Comment: This solution is fine, but the reasoning is incorrect: You can close either stream. Closing a wrapper stream like ZipOutputStream will also close the lower-level FileOutputStream.

Comment: Notice that Java 7 has introduced a [try-with-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block which makes this kind of code much cleaner!!

Answer (score 4):

You should track if you added stuff the zip stream and close it only when things were added:

```
ZipOutputStream zos = null; 
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("...")
int itemsAdded=0;
try
{
    zos = new ZipOutputStream(file);
    //
    //..
    // itemsAdded++; 
}
finally
{
    if ( itemsAdded > 0 ) {
         zos.close();
    } else {
         file.close();
    }
}
```

of if you don't need the count just use a `boolean` flag.

Comment: The zip file remains open and locked that way... How to close it?

Comment: @lucho added some code to close the file when the zip stream is empty. take a look.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of closing the stream only when things are added, what I did is a condition check to see if there was anything to zip, before running the zip code. This helped me to simplify the process and I think can be used in general to handle the "ZIP file must have at least one entry" problem. True that closing `zos` may throw other exceptions, but that is rare.

I think it is problem with Java, that doesn't handle the case when there are no files to zip.

i.e:

```
int itemsToAdd=0;
//....

if ( itemsToAdd > 0 ) {

    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(file);
    try {
        //add files to zip
    }
    finally {
        zos.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 7 or above, you can use try-with-resources for better readability

For example:

```
try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("..."))) {
    // do something with zos
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 7 or above, **just try-with-resource would be enough to close ZipOutputStream**, and there is no need to call close() or closeEntry() methods to flush the buffer data and close the stream.

Checked the code of ZipOutputStream::close(), it would call finish(), and inside the finish method, there is a check as following, which means that the closeEntry would be called automatically when the stream closed.

```
public void finish() throws IOException {
ensureOpen();
if (finished) {
    return;
}
if (current != null) {
    closeEntry();
}
// write central directory
long off = written;
for (XEntry xentry : xentries)
    writeCEN(xentry);
writeEND(off, written - off);
finished = true;
```

}